# How to assign a concrete implementation of generic type to list of generic type

Tags: c#

I have been trying to understand why the following generates a compile error, and how to get around the error.

```
public interface IA { }
public class AImp : IA { }

public interface IConsumer<T> where T : IA
{
    void Consume(T val);
}

public class Consumer : IConsumer<AImp>
{
    public void Consume(AImp val)
    {
        // do smth
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<IConsumer<IA>> l1 = new List<IConsumer<IA>>();
        l1.Add(new Consumer());  // generate compile error cannot convert from consumer to IConsumer<IA>

    }
}
```

If I can create `IList<IA> l = new List<IA>();` and asign `l.Add(new AImp());` , I dont see why the generic type is not working. Perhaps I am missing something fundamental.

I haven't been able to find any promising leads from google either.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: @TheGeneral, I believe covariance only works for return types and not arguments

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want `public class Consumer : IConsumer<AImp>` and not `public class Consumer : IConsumer<IA>` ?

Comment: It's very interesting, when you're `out`, here `interface IConsumer<out T>`, there is compile-time error of invalid variance with `IConsumer.Consume` method. According to MSDN, _You cannot use a covariant type parameter as a generic type constraint for interface methods._, it is normal, but that's not very good for you, IMHO, you can only change `class Consumer : IConsumer<AImp>` to `class Consumer : IConsumer<IA>`, that will solve variance compile-time errors.

Comment: I think you just have to cast the `new Consumer()` to `(IConsumer<AImp>) `

Comment: Because `Consumer` is not an `IConsumer<IA>` - if it were you would be able to define a class `class BImp : IA {}` and then do `IConsumer<IA> c = new Consumer(); c.Consume(new BImp());`. This would not be safe because `BImp` is not compatible with `AImp`. To put it another way, `Consumer` cannot consume _any_ `IA`, just one particular subtype of `IA` namely `AImp`.

Comment: Put that way, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score -1):

You get an error message because the Consumer does not inherit from IConsumer<T>. It inherits from IConsumer<AImp>.

There is special technique to use this kind of template class, you have to create a IConsumer interface which is not generic type like this:

```
public interface IA { }
public class AImp : IA { }

public interface IConsumer
{
}

public interface IConsumer<T> : IConsumer
    where T : IA
{
    void Consume(T val);
}

public class Consumer : IConsumer<AImp>
{
    public void Consume(AImp val)
    {
        // do smth
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<IConsumer> l1 = new List<IConsumer>();
        l1.Add(new Consumer());  // ok
    }
}
```

This basically the idea behind the IEnumerable and ICollection generic and non generic versions.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the solution is to declare the empty interface `IConsumer`? If so, it may be worth reading Microsoft Code Analysis rule [CA1040](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1040-avoid-empty-interfaces?view=vs-2017). Also, when you get something out of `l1` you can't do anything with it unless you cast it to something else. Yeuch.

Comment: P.S. I'm intrigued by the 3 comments above mine, and wonder what the other half of that conversation was; but you only need [15 rep to flag as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).